# insert a string(with spaces) into mysql using php from my iphone app

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, sql-insert

I am trying to save a string (Address) entered by a user in my iphone app into mysql database. I am using php to accomplish this. I have a few problems.

Here is my code in php:

```
...
$guestadd1 = $_GET["guestadd1"];
$guestadd2 = $_GET["guestadd2"];
$guestcity = $_GET["guestcity"];
...
```

And here is the mysql query:

```
 mysql_query( "INSERT INTO HMS_GUESTS( GUESTTYPE, GUESTLNAME, GUESTFNAME, GUESTADDRESS1,
               GUESTADDRESS2, GUESTCITY, GUESTSTATE, GUESTPOSTCODE, GUESTWORKPHONE) VALUES 
               ('$guestType', '$guestLname', '$guestFname', '$guestadd1', '$guestadd2', 
               '$guestcity', '$gueststate', '$guestpostal', '$guestWphone') ", $con) or 
               die(mysql_error());
```

**1**
But I am unable to insert the data with spaces. If I try saving it without space, I am able to insert. How can i insert with spaces?

**2**
I have two types of guests: Personal and Professional. So, more than one entry can have the same guest types. So, when I am trying to insert the second guest from one type, I am getting Duplicate value for key error. How can I overcome this and insert the entry?

Any help appreciated. Thank you :)

**EDIT**
Including my objective-c code

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://127.0.0.1/hms.php?guesttype=%@&
guestLname=%@&guestFname=%@&guestadd1=%@&guestadd2=%@&guestcity=%@&
gueststate=%@&guestpostal=%@&guestWphone=%@", guestID, self.name1.text, self.name2.text,
self.address1.text, self.address2.text, self.city.text, self.state.text, self.postal.text,
self.phone.text, self.fax.text];
    // to execute php code
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    // to receive the returned value
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And mysql table structure:

```
Guest Type  | Guest First Name | Guest Last Name | ADDRESS LINE 1 | ADDRESS LINE 2 | CITY | STATE | POSTAL |  WORKPHONE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Personal    | blah             |  blah           | blah            | blah          | blah | blah  | blah   |  blah
Professional| blah             |  blah           | blah            | blah          | blah | blah  | blah   |  blah
```

SO, in the address columm or possibly anywhere..i will come across spaces in arguments which i am not able to insert.

And if I now try to add another guest to the table, say type Personal, I am getting this error: Duplicate entry '1-1-PERSONAL-11' for key 1

Comment: What error are you getting?  What is the primary key on your table?  Are you sure it's a space screwing stuff up, and not say, an apostrophe?

Comment: please post your table structure also...

Comment: If I must guess: Your app does not properly create the URL, so PHP is not to blame. The data that goes inside a GET URL has to be url-encoded, i.e. a space character either has to be a "+" (plus sign), or "%20" (hexadecimal byte code, preceded by a percent sign). And now go ahead and think about how plus-signs are actually transmitted...

Comment: @MikeChristensen : Please review my question once again.. i have added the details :) TY

Comment: @Akam : Please review my question once again.. i have added the details :) TY

Comment: @Sven : Please review my question once again.. i have added the details :) TY

Comment: I can read that objective-c code, and although I have no experience with it, I assume my theory is right and there is no url encoding taking place anywhere. The examples I saw when doing a quick google search all looked way more complicated to get to the final url.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not use the mysql_query function, and don't construct your queries using string interpolation (or concatenation for that matter). That kind of solution leaves you wide open for a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. I'd recommend using something like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and taking advantage of parameter binding. Otherwise you have a major security hole that any idiot can exploit.